# django - display all groups with their users

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-orm

With django auth group and user models, I want to query all groups with their users. (user_id list would be fine).

I tried

```
Group.objects.all().select_related('user')
```

But it isn't working:

```
FieldError: Invalid field name(s) given in select_related: 'user'. Choices are: (none)
```

Comment: Please show your models definition and actual error message. `Isn't working` is vague.

Comment: I didn't define any models, I used the User and Group models from django.auth.models